# Angular-NG8001 not known element error. How solve it?

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I have a problem with my Angular project. I have a project structure: [app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T08Dz.png). In my app.module.ts the code is below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { bmiComponent } from './bmi/bmi.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    bmiComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the bmi folder I have a bmi.component.ts with this code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-bmi-calculator', 
    standalone : true,
    templateUrl: '.bmi.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        '.bmi.component.css'
    ]
})
export class bmiComponent{
    weight : number;
    height : number;

constructor(){
    this.weight = 50;
    this.height = 1.6;
    }
}
```

In my app.component.html if i wrote the  tags i get an error:
NG8001: 'app-bmi-calculator' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-bmi-calculator' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'app-bmi-calculator' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
   How can i solve the error?
   Thank you for your help!

I tried in the bmi.component.ts standalone: true int the @Component block but didn't solve the probelem.

Comment: Standalone bmiComponent needs to be imported in the imports array of NgModule decorator to be available in app.component's template. bmiComponent also should not be specified in declarations of AppModule if it's standalone.

Answer (score 0):

A standalone component is a type of component that doesn’t belong to any specific Angular module. Before Angular version 14, when you created a component, you typically had to include it in the declaration array of a module; otherwise, Angular would throw an error during compilation.

best solution is creating a project that all of its components be standalone.

but in your case you can use modules and make your app.component.ts standalone and bootstrap it in app.config.ts. remove bmiComponent from declarations of AppModule and insert it to imports array of app.component.ts.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bmi-calculator', 
  standalone : true,
  imports: [bmiComponent, ...],
  .
  .
  .
})
export class AppComponent{
  .
  .
}
```

IMPORTANT:

but if your app.component.ts is not standalone and you want to use bmiComponent as standalone you have to remove bmiComponent from declarations of AppModule and insert it to imports array of AppModule.

Comment: I need to import the BmiComponent in the app.component.ts. And work. Thank for your help!